# How to differentiate a linux command execution from command line and a program

Tags: linux

I have a unix command 'abc' which gives me an output
This abc lies on my server.

But when i run this command from server, i want to restrict the output of it to be seen by people.
By the above statement , i meant..
For eg. If i say:

> ls dirname

I can see the output of the above command on the console.

So, if the command is run from command-line, i dont want to have echoed on the console. I cant use /dev/null as I am using the same command from my program where I need the output to be assigned to a variable and then use it further in my application.

However, I want to get the output of this command when I call this from my program.
How can I differentiate the call in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `restrict the output of it to be seen by people`: unclear. Could you edit question and elaborate a bit. And how do you call that command from your program ? In what language ?

Answer (score 1):

The command `whoami` gives you the current logged user, and the command `last -i` outputs information of the last logged users in the system, including the IP address (3rd column) and the timestamp or a string stating that the user is stil logged in.

With that in mind you could pipe these commands:

```
last -i | grep $(whoami) | grep 'still logged in'
```

which will provide an output like this:

```
(username) pts/2        0.0.0.0          Wed Dec 23 18:58   still logged in   
(username) :0           0.0.0.0          Wed Dec 23 11:13   still logged in
```

so if you are running a shell in the same host, the IP will be `0.0.0.0` and different otherwise. You can extract the IP string by piping `awk` at the end of the command.

---

However, addhering to the philosophy in unix systems of [Do One Thing and Do It Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well), I'd suggest a different approach, split your command into 2 different commands:

- A command to be used by the clients, where the output is whatever you
  want the clients to see
- Another command (offering 2 options, since there isnt much detail in the question):

  - Either extending the first command, adding the additional output, and using this one from your application
  - Or just generating the additional output, and using a combination of the 2 commands from your application

Some of the benefits you can get by following this approach:

- Performing checks to verify where the command was issued from, is no longer necessary
- Avoid coupling issues
- Easier to maintain

---

**Updated**: added the means to extract the IP of the current user at the beggining of the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, this is a 3rd party command executable that I have to use in my application. I don't see a way to use it as you suggested

Comment: then a possible solution would be, to use that command in your app, but wrap it with your own command for the clients, where you just filter the output

Comment: edited the question adding the means to obtain the IP of the user with shell commands

Answer (score 1):

You were a little vague on the complete setup, so I'll have to infer a few things.  Since you mentioned, "my" server, I assume you can set permissions on files, change ownership on files, etc (e.g. you can become root).

I also have to infer that the target `abc` program just produces some output and doesn't need to modify any files to speak of [other than (e.g.) `/tmp/temp.$$`]

As an example, let's do this from your home directory.  Move the program `abc` to `$HOME/private_bin` and set the directory permission to `700` which means that only *you* can execute it.

Create a second directory: `$HOME/public_bin` that has normal permissions.  Create a "launcher" program [let's call it `abcpub`] and put it in this directory.  Set the permissions of `abcpub` to `4741`.  It's now a `setuid` program.  Note that *any* non-root user may do this for files they own.  It is *not* like creating a `sudo` because an ordinary user would need to do `chown root ...`

Now we're set ...

You can access the real `abc` program anytime you want.  Others have *no* direct access to `abc`.

The launcher `abcpub` will allow *others* to have access to `abc`, but the launcher can apply whatever restrictions you desire:  including no access, output to /dev/null, etc.  `abcpub` can look at `getuid` and `geteuid` to determine who is executing it [you or somebody else]

We did the above example using your own uid and home directory.  But, we can repeat the process by creating an "abc" user in /etc/passwd and a `/home/abc`.  The abc user could be set up with a shell of `/sbin/nologin`.  Thus, it's similar to `nobody` and it can't hurt anything.

It may be even better doing this by creating a `setgrp` program instead of `setuid` as that allows better comingling.  The original user could retain their user permissions but still get access via the new group.

Also, it *may* be possible to configure `sudo` to get what you want.